# Google Place API Photo Meta Data in Xamarin:Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-api, xamarin.android, google-places-api

I try get photos from Places API.
The main code look that :

```
private void GetPhotos(Intent data)
    {

        var placePicked = PlacePicker.GetPlace(this, data);

        string placeId = placePicked.Id;
        Task photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.GetPlacePhotos(placeId);
        if (photoMetadataResponse.IsComplete)
        {

            var  photos =(PlacePhotoMetadataResponse) photoMetadataResponse.Result;
            PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.PhotoMetadata;
            if (photoMetadataBuffer.Count > 0)
            {
                IPlacePhotoMetadata photoMetaData = (IPlacePhotoMetadata) photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0);
                Task photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.GetPhoto(photoMetaData);
                if (photoResponse.IsComplete)
                {

                    PlacePhotoResponse photoResult = (PlacePhotoResponse) photoResponse.Result;
                    Bitmap bitmap = photoResult.Bitmap;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I have problem when I going to try initialize:

`IPlacePhotoMetadata photoMetaData = (IPlacePhotoMetadata) photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0);`

The exception is :

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

mGeoDataClient is waiting for object from IPlacePhotoMetadata. I was checked what object `photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0)`

Returned namespace was :

> android.common.data.zzc

Totally this object doesn't tell me much... How I Can cast photoMetadataBuffer on IPlacePhotoMetadata? Or where would be something mistake from my side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use the Xamarin's Async wrappers or directly decompose the Android based tasks (review the `TasksExtensions.AsAsync` which Xamarin wrappers use) in order to obtain the correct instance the Android Task returns:

## Xamarin's async wrappers example:

```
private async void GetPhotosAsync(Intent data)
{
    var placePicked = PlacePicker.GetPlace(this, data);

    string placeId = placePicked.Id;
    var photoMetadataResponse = await mGeoDataClient.GetPlacePhotosAsync(placeId);
    var photoMetadataBuffer = photoMetadataResponse.PhotoMetadata;
    if (photoMetadataBuffer.Count > 0)
    {
        var photoMetaData = (IPlacePhotoMetadata)photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0);
        var photoResponse = await mGeoDataClient.GetPhotoAsync(photoMetaData);
        var bitmap = photoResponse.Bitmap;

        ~~~
    }
}
```

Note: I'm assuming GetPhotosAsync will return something other than `void` when you get the rest the method flushed out...

Update:

```
private async void GetPhotos(Intent data)
{
    var placePicked = PlacePicker.GetPlace(this, data);

    string placeId = placePicked.Id;
    using (var photoMetadataResponse = await mGeoDataClient.GetPlacePhotosAsync(placeId))
    using (var photoMetadataBuffer = photoMetadataResponse.PhotoMetadata)
    {
        foreach (var item in photoMetadataBuffer)
        {
            using (var photoResponse = await mGeoDataClient.GetPhotoAsync(item))
            {
                var bitmap = photoResponse.Bitmap;
                photoResponse.Dispose();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :) The app continue to Break Mode :( In BM I see that message : `...all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).` but when I check Output. It is System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. The problem is on memory?

Comment: @Gracjan which line/variable is the invalid cast? (IPlacePhotoMetadata or the GetPhotoAsync or ...?)

Comment: Step Over : `var photoMetaData = (IPlacePhotoMetadata)photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0);` I check what the photoMetadataBuffer returned value : `{com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzar@720e984}` to other variable (without cast)

Comment: I checked everything in official doc on google : [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/photos), no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @Gracjan I am not in front of my code, but try using the enumerator instead, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank's a lot of for your help :) It is working [photo](https://imgur.com/a/w2T46Jk)